# 404 problems when using persian slugs in django

Tags: python, django

Hi i am using django and some slug fields . But when I use persian slugs I got 404 errors !
when I use English slugs , I got no error .

here is the urls.py :
`re_path(r'^details/(?P<slug>[\w-]+)/', Details_view , name="Details_page"),`

I am not sure that I am using right regular expression !

Comment: Can you provide an example of phrases that need to be slugified?

Answer (score 1):

```py
from django.urls import re_path
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

re_path(r'^details/(?P<slug>[-\w\u0600-\u06FF]+)/$', Details_view, name="Details_page"),
```

- `[-\w\u0600-\u06FF]` allows for Persian characters `(Unicode range: \u0600 to \u06FF)` in addition to the existing English characters `(\w)` and `/$` ensuring that there are no additional characters after the slug.

Comment: still got the error!

Comment: The regex pattern will not match all Persian words.

Comment: @Alirezajavanpour what is the error?

Comment: its a 404 page that could not match any url !